# Twilio Flex - transfer chat task

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I am building an internal support tool with Twilio Flex. The first rollout will just handle chats from either the WebChat widget or SMS. I have not found a way to transfer a chat task to another available agent. I have found the [warm transfer for voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/warm-transfer), but have not found a way for chat tasks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It turns out that one of the Twilio Expert Services team has already created a plugin that might help. Check out the code and the details in the repo here: https://github.com/johnfischelli/plugin-chat-sms-transfer.

Comment: open source plugins are absolutely awesome!

Comment: I like this answer better than mine for sure.

Comment: There are a bunch of plugins that have been built by members of the expert services team here at Twilio. We need to gather them into a place that can help people, like yourself, discover them better. I'm pretty glad they exist too though!

Comment: It would be really nice to see a list of those plugins as well. thats a great idea!

Comment: I have started that list for the community here. Please feel free to let me know best place to maintain this list. Ill be happy to accept a few contributions and just to get the repo into a state where flex engineers can fork and maintain. What do you think? https://github.com/jstallm/awesome-twilio-flex-plugins

Comment: This is awesome. Will add to this as I find plugins too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe this is supported with todays version of flex. Not without customization.

Comment: If I was going to try and make it work, do you have any recommendations as to how to start and what path to take?

Comment: If you can customize the UI, you can likely add a custom transfer button, and then create backend api endpoint which is where you ahve to program the most. On the backend, youll have to work with their SDK and create a custom new task with perhaps some attributes that create a relationship between intended transfer recipeint. Just an idea.

Comment: also, you may need to think about if you are looking to do a warm transfer or simply pass the chat without consultation